# Vue.js - How to create child component's DOM element outside of it's parent component's DOM element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a child component, but instead of putting it's DOM element inside parent's as it is by default, I want to put it somewhere else.

I want to create child component of modal component, but there is a issue because the modal component is overflow: hidden, and I need the child component to be visible outside of the modal. The best solution I've found is how Vuetify do it with their v-menu component (link below). They simply not create child component's DOM element as a child node of it's parent component's DOM element, but instead they put it somewhere else.
I read their code on github, but I'm quite confused with the implementation, and found nothing in Vue documentation about this.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create a child outside its parent's DOM element, but you might get the effect you want with `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is too late. But what you are looking for is [Teleport](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html)

```
<button @click="open = true">Open Modal</button>

<Teleport to="body">
  <div v-if="open" class="modal">
    <p>Hello from the modal!</p>
    <button @click="open = false">Close</button>
  </div>
</Teleport>
```

This places the element in the desired dom element. You can also id in the attribute "to"

Answer (score -1):

Child:

```
<template>
    <div>
         I'm CHILD
         <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Parent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Child>
            <span>I'm parent</span>
        </Child>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: Thank you, next time I will explain better how to solve the problem